# What do you call a hairstyle that make it so that the hair doesn't fly all over the place?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am thinking there's an adjective to qualify these types of hair, but I am not sure what it might be. I am not looking for the exact word for this style, but a word that describes all styles that make it so that the hair doesn't move too much in the wind.

Comment: At least in US English, women sometimes refer to "wearing their hair **up**". I guess it is short for "pinned-up" as in Andrew's answer, but just plain "up" is a good general expression for a variety of styles: bun, pinned up into a mass of medusa-curls, chignon, wreath of braids (as in your picture), etc. Usage example: "If I'd known how hot it is in here, I would have put my hair up." "She used to wear her hair up, but now she doesn't even have time to comb it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pinned** or **pinned-up** might work as a general term, but there are several dozen other more specific ways to decoratively "constrain" hair.  The hair in your picture has been partly **braided** and then pinned.

Often these have their own names, far too many to list.  For example [here is a list of only *some* of the different kinds of braids](https://www.stylecraze.com/articles/different-types-of-braids/), all of which can be pinned up in ways that might even have their own unique names.  If you are really interested, YouTube has hundreds of videos on how to braid and style hair, along with the names of those styles.

The style in your picture looks a bit like some kind of woven crown, like a [laurel wreath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_wreath).  I expect it has a specific name so that, if you want to a hair stylist who does this kind of thing and requested it, they would know exactly what you want.

(Edit)  Found it.  It's called a [crown braid](https://hairmotive.com/crown-braid/), with many variations.

Answer (score 7):

Styles where the hair is brushed away from the face and pinned or tied up are generally categorized as **"[updos](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/updo)."**

They can be as simple as a ponytail or bun, or as complicated as the braid in your picture.

Comment: in the U.S. this is the commonly used, one-word term for the pictured hairstyle and similar.

Comment: Yes, here, a braided updo. :)